# Proportionnal RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to achieve the following:

- a picture, as a background, which resize according to the screen size
- I want to put button on top of this picture, while maintaining a proportional position to the picture width and height.

See the example:

[image]

The background is an image with the fill_parent settings for width/height.The yellow squares are buttons on top of this picture.

So, how can I keep the button on the exact same position on top of the picture with different screen size, using relative layout (or others layout)

Comment: have you tried percent support library. It has PercentRelativeLayout in which you can define child view by percentage like margin percentage. In this image if image maintains its proportion then you can have solution by finding the height and width of button in percentage relative to background image and adding marginLeft and top to align on top of picture

Comment: Waow, I did not saw this, thanks for pointing out, seems to be the solution

Comment: Since the human body is "symmetrical", meaning that the top and the bottom parts are more or less equally distant from the "center", you could put an empty generic View (sized 0, 0) and relate the other Views to it. For the foot and head you can use the parent bottom and top alignment, along with some margins. This is how we did it before the Percent_xyz things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the ["Percent Support Library"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html) as stated by @subhash